# Is possible to execute sql query direct in org mode?

Tags: org-mode, sql

windows 10, emacs 26.1

I know that in org mode I can insert source code and **execute** them. Nice.

But what about sql:

Here in my.org  file:

```
 #+name: some_query
   #+BEGIN_SRC sql
      SELECT * FROM invoice WHERE id IN (1,2,3)
   #+END_SRC
```

Is it possible to execute query direct in org mode and get result?

Comment: Yes: there is `ob-sql.el` and `ob-sqlite.el`. The latter is specific to `sqlite` but the former can handle different database engines. Read the beginning of `ob-sql.el` to see how to use it and check out also the [SQL doc on Worg](https://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/babel/languages/ob-doc-sql.html).

Answer (score 1):

Yes. `ob-sql` is what I would use. Link to documentation with examples: https://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/babel/languages/ob-doc-sql.html

You can specify your connection credentials directly as parameters of the source block:

```
#+begin_src sql :engine postgresql :dbhost HOSTNAME :dbuser USERNAME :dbpassword PASSWORD :database DBNAME
SELECT * FROM TABLE
LIMIT 100
#+end_src
```

The results are formatted as org-mode table in `RESULTS` block below after execution.

You could also configure the credentials under a header with ([source](https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/e9lrcp/how_to_use_sqlmode_or_org_babel_to_execute_mssql/fakr7nw?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3)):

```
 * some header that the sql source block will be in
  :PROPERTIES:
  :header-args+: :results table
  :header-args+: :engine mssql
  :header-args+: :dbhost 123.123.123.123
  :header-args+: :database database-name-a
  :header-args+: :dbuser username-a
  :header-args+: :dbpassword password-a
  :END:
```